# How to replace space/character with specified character after first numeric value in string using C#?

Tags: c#, str-replace

I have `String` containing `Special Characters & Numeric Values` .

```
Eg:
3-3 3 
3-3"3/4
3-3-3/4
3-3 3/4
3 3 3
3'3 3

Output must be:
    3f3 3 
    3f3"3/4
    3f3-3/4
    3f3 3/4
    3f3 3
    3f3 3
```

I have tried using :

```
public static string ReplaceFirst(string text, string search, string replace)
        {
            int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
            if (pos < 0)
            {
                return text;
            }
            return text.Substring(0, pos) + replace + text.Substring(pos + search.Length);
        }
```

using above code it replaces the first occurrence with specified character this works fine.

```
Eg: 3-3 3 Output: 3f3 3
```

But for `3 3-3 Output: 3 3f3` according to code is correct. but i want to replace space/character after first numeric which would be `3f3-3`

Help Appreciated!

Comment: is every line a seperate string? Or are there new line chars in?

Comment: yes @Jeroen1984 every line is separate string these are some of the samples!

Comment: You mean after 1st numeric, the space or - or , should be replaced with f....... nothing else. right? 
Is all strings are separate?
Is first char will be numeric always?

Comment: hello @GAPS,yes first char will be numeric i mean the same as you specified!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple loops should work.

```
for(int i =0; i < myListOfStrings.Count; i++)
{
    char[] chars = myListOfStrings[i].ToCharArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < chars.Count(); j++)
    {
       if (Char.IsDigit(chars[j]))
       {
           if(j + 1 < chars.Count())
           {
              chars[j + 1] = 'f'; //'f' being your replacing character
              myListOfStrings[i] = new string(chars);
           }
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

Output examples

```
myListOfStrings.Add("3-3 3");
myListOfStrings.Add("3-3-3/4");
myListOfStrings.Add("3 3-3");
myListOfStrings.Add("3 3 3");

3f3 3
3f3-3/4
3f3-3
3f3 3
```

Update from comments

```
for (int i = 0; i < myListOfStrings.Count; i++)
{
     char[] chars = myListOfStrings[i].ToCharArray();
     for (int j = 0; j < chars.Count(); j++)
     {
         if (!Char.IsDigit(chars[j]))
         {
             if (j + 1 < chars.Count())
             {
                 chars[j] = 'f'; //'f' being your replacing character
                 myListOfStrings[i] = new string(chars);
             }
             break;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: hello @keyboardP, when i use 10-3 3 then it gives 1f-3 3 which is not correct it must be 10f3- 3 will please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: You've changed the requirement (or might be a typo). Why does `10-3 3` become `10f3- 3`? Shouldn't it be `10f3 3`? If so, it should be an easy fix and I'll update the answer.

Comment: please don't misunderstand @keyboardP, i have mentioned that these are samples and i need to replace first numeric it means 3,10,200  in 3-3 3, 10-3 3,200 3 3 and so on. but, thanks for the sample. I have modified it and posted. Sorry it have being misspelled above comment. i apologize! Thank u!

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE - No that's fine, but your comment changed the format which breaks my original post. You said `10f3- 3`. Why has the dash moved? Edit - Just saw your answer. It was a typo in your comment. You can simplify your code a bit (see update)

Comment: but using your existing  code when string is 3-3 3 outputs to 3f3 3 but, when value is 10-3 3 it shows 1f3 3 which is wrong so..!

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE - Look at your first comment again. You say `10-3 3` should `10f3- 3`. Why has the `-` moved to the right of the 3? Shouldn't it be `10f3 3`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34606/discussion-between-shekhar-shete-and-keyboardp)

Answer (score 0):

```
var match = Regex.Match(text, search); //To search for any special character, use @"\W" as the second parameter
var editable = text.ToCharArray();
editable[match.Index] = replace[0];
text = new String(editable);
return text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

Modified Code:

```
string S="10-3 3";
char[] chars = S.ToCharArray();
                for (int j = 0; j < chars.Count(); j++)
                {
                    if (Char.IsDigit(chars[j]))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (j + 1 < chars.Count())
                        {
                            chars[j] = 'f'; //'f' being  replacing character
                            S = new string(chars);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

Output: 10f3 3
```